# Prononciation de « u » proche de « ou »

Tags: prononciation, voyelles

J'ai toujours pensé que « u » est prononcé /y/ (dans l'alphabet phonétique international — le même son que la lettre allemande *ü*). Mais j'écoute une radio française et certains gens y prononcent « u » comme /u/ (lettre de l'alphabet phonétique international qui correspond au « ou » français). J'ai remarqué cela plusieurs fois, donc je ne crois pas que j'ai seulement mal écouté.

Est-ce que la prononciation de « u » comme un « ou » est la caractéristique d'un dialecte régional (cette radio est une radio régionale de Toulouse) ?

Quelques exemples que j'ai entendu :

- Un homme à la radio a prononcé « sujet » comme si le mot était « soujet » (je ne pense pas que c'était un homophone, « sujet » allait bien dans ce contexte), la première voyelle était clairement « ou ».
- D'autres fois, j'ai entendu « ou », par exemple dans le mot « commune » mais ce n'était pas aussi clair que pour « sujet » ; ce son était entre « u » et « ou ».
- Plus récemment, dans « sûr », « candidature » et « persécuter », de la part de trois personnes différentes. Au début j'ai entendu « ou », mais ce n'était pas très clair, parce qu'ils prononcent le début de cette lettre comme un « u » et la fin comme un « ou ».

Peut-être que la prononciation en question est un son entre un clair /y/ et un /u/, et c'était seulement exagéré dans ce « sujet » que j'ai entendu. Mais j'ai aussi entendu un très clair /y/ dans la bouche d'autres gens sur la même radio, donc je suis sûr que ce n'est pas le même son.

Il est possible que je me trompe. Peut-être que je croyais la prononciation extrême (proche du « y » comme dans « Syrie ») et que je suis surpris d'apprendre que c'est plus proche de « ou ». La prononciation qui, je crois, est correcte est [ici](http://french.about.com/library/media/wavs/u.wav) et c'est clairement différent du « u » que j'entends à la radio.

Comment: Il manque des exemples pour que l'on perçoive mieux ce qui est en jeu.

Comment: [« Caramba encore ouné fois trop à droite »](http://moserm.free.fr/tintinetlesmechants/dossier8.html)

Comment: Étrange. Peut-être un locuteur avec un accent très prononcé ou avec une langue maternelle étrangère

Comment: C'est difficile de juger avec un son isolé, mais je trouve http://french.about.com/library/media/wavs/u.wav atypique, intermédiaire entre [y] et [i].

Comment: *Syrie* se prononce /si.ʁi/ en français.

Comment: en belgique, on dit parfois Louis et pas lui. Les semi-voyelles /ɥ/ et /w/ que l'on écrit aussi u, ou, se sont fusionnées en /w/... mais les voyelles, elles-mêmes, elles restent distinctes...

Comment: @Gilles: je pensais que c'est bon et c'était mal - merci pour coriger mon erreur de prononciation!

Comment: @hunter Oui, en Belgique, nous avons un petit défaut de prononciation du son "u" dans certains cas (et ce n'est évidemment pas le cas pour tous les Belges!). Mais de là à prononcer sujet "soujet", je ne pense pas! Je pencherais plus pour une personne d'origine étrangère, comme les pays de l'Est (Pologne, Russie...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Je ne connais aucune « prononciation régionale » où le *u* est prononcé « ou » de manière systématique.

Il peut en revanche y avoir des dialectes (ou « langues régionales » ...) où un *u* écrit se prononcerait « ou » ; c'est probablement le cas du corse et de l'alsacien, vu qu'ils dérivent respectivement de l'italien et de l'allemand.

Après, il faudrait voir des exemples de ce que vous avez entendu pour juger de ces cas particuliers.

*Edit:* le de TV5Monde a [une page intéressante sur la prononciation de /y/](http://apprendre.tv5monde.com/fr/apprendre-francais/prononciation-le-son-u).

Comment: Merci! J'ai ajouté quelque examples. Je vais ajouter plus quand j'entends une autre personne parlant comme ça. Si je entends d'où est cette personne, je vais l'écrire aussi.

Comment: J'ai entendu cette prononciation d'u autre fois et j'ai trouvé que ce n'est pas "ou" clair, mais un son entre "u" et "ou". Voyez mon EDIT2, s'il vous plaît.

Comment: Well, you have my answer to tell you what I see as common in France (I'm French btw). There can be a million reasons why you may hear something else than /y/: weird regional/foreign accents, your not being used to French sounds or the variety of pronounciations, ... Check my edit, I added an interesting link

Comment: Thanks for the link, it proved there's wider range of "u" pronunciation in French than I originally thought. The very first sound record in your link ("dessus") is very similar to what I misheard as "something between u and ou". For me, the difference between both extreme variants of "u"  pronuntiation (close to "y" as in my link or to "ou" as in yours) seem as big as the difference between that "dessus/dessous". However, I'll get accustomed to this, though it might take a while. Thank you again for helping me make a big step towards learning this!

Answer (score 5):

Compte tenu du contexte (radio régionale de Toulouse), je propose trois hypothèses:

- L'interlocuteur est d'origine espagnole. Les Pyrénées ont toujours été perméables, surtout depuis la guerre civile espagnole.
- L'interlocuteur est un locuteur natif occitan (c'est-à-dire très agé). En occitan, sauf le gascon, le u se prononce ou; et à Toulouse le dialecte dominant est le languedocien.
- L'interlocuteur est étranger. Entre les universités et les constructeurs aéronautiques, Toulouse attire beaucoup de monde.

Comment: J'apporte une petite correction concernant l'occitan : en languedocien on ne prononce pas le "u"  \u\ ("ou") mais bien \y\, comme en français. J'ai la chance d'être un locuteur natif de l'occitan à 18 ans :)